# how to take multiple rows from a query and and analyze it for 1 row in new query

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot, sybase

I have developed a query for the problem below. However, it is not showing desired results. Anyone have ideas?

### table 1

```
ID FRUIT 
1  APPLE
1  APPLE
1  MANGO
```

### Table 2

```
country  id
USA       1
UK        2
```

If count of fruit name is greater than 1, i need "yes" for festival and "no" for zero count.

```
select country ,id 
CASE 
when table1.count > 1 and table1.fruit='APPLE' 
then 'Y'
else 'N'
END as apple_festival,
CASE 
when table1.count > 1 and table1.fruit='MANGO' 
then 'Y'
else 'N'
END as mango_festival,
CASE 
when table1.count > 1 and table1.fruit='BANANA' 
then 'Y'
else 'N'
END as Banana festival, JOIN (SELECT id,fruit,count from table1  group by id,fruit) table1 on table1.id=table2.id
```

I want results like this:

```
COUNTRY id apple_festival mango_festival Banana_festival
USA     1         Y            Y              N
```

However, I am getting this:

```
COUNTRY id apple_festival mango_festival Banana_festival
USA     1         Y            N              N
USA     1         N            Y              N
```

people can use this fiddle for helping me..

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Your results suggest that the condition is `> 0`, not `> 1` -- and that is very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    t2.country,
    t2.id,
    case when max(case when t1.fruit = 'apple'  then 1 end) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end apple_festival,
    case when max(case when t1.fruit = 'mango'  then 1 end) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end mango_festival,
    case when max(case when t1.fruit = 'banana' then 1 end) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end banana_festival
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t2.id, t2.country
```

Comment: in group by there should be more apple_festival and banana festival and such right. and the above query is not running .can u please check the below fiddle [link] (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b362e97227d0ac22670c1b50f34f3c9f)

Comment: @amarenderreddyjali: I edited the query so it runs on Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Query. Running in SQL Server.

```
  select  country,ID,
  apple_festival =Case when max(case when Fruit='Apple' and cnt>=1  then 1 end)=1 then 'Yes' Else 'No' End,
  Mango_festival =Case when max(case when Fruit='Mango' and cnt>=1  then 1 end)=1 then 'Yes' Else 'No' End,   
  Banana_festival =Case when max(case when Fruit='Banana' and cnt>=1  then 1 end)=1 then 'Yes' Else 'No' End   
from table2 mt1
cross apply (
    select FRUIT,cnt=count(*) from table1 mt2  
    where mt2.id=mt1.id
    group by FRUIT
) as fruittable                    
 group by country,ID
```

---

Please ensure the Count logic (whether ">=1" or ">1" )